# I cant get the mobile viewport to behave and scale properly

Tags: css, html, viewport, meta-tags

I need someone to view the source on my page and please tell me why the mobile version keeps opening up big, only needing to be scaled down after manually. I need it to open at the correct size and stay at that size.  Please view the source on the following link:

http://directsellers.org/NeverTakeNo4Answer/LetsGo.html

Note: i feel i've tried nearly every meta viewport version there is all with no luck.  I feel the problem may be deeper but i cant identify it.  Please help me figure this out so i can move on with my life.

Comment: Why do use a fixed width for your viewport? Try to change `<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">` to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">` and then use percentage value for `#Container`(`width: 90%;`) in media query.

Comment: i just did that, if you look quickly before  change it back, you can see how destroyed it all looks

Comment: You have to do a lot works to achieve a responsive website. For example, in media query change all elements' width value which has a fixed value with percentage value.

Comment: what if i change them to width: device-width; is that still eligible?

Comment: yes, in the css file

Comment: No, it is not. what viewport(`width: device-width`) does is that when you give percentage value in your media query, it is calculated regarding to the devices width. For example, when you give `width:90%` in your media query, it mean 90% of device width.

Comment: i had tried it in the css, and it did display as should, but per your suggestion, i guess it will probably break and should be 100% instead of device-width, yes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100733/discussion-between-alex-and-willinglearner).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your #Container style isn't using percentages on your 400px media breakpoint. Also the font size is 1.5em

Comment: i tried to use percentages, the whole layout blows up. So i just set it at 1000px

Comment: There is a lot of stuff that needs fixing here. But here is a quick list. Change all widths to percentages, the background image you have in #Headline try background-size: cover

Answer (score 0):

Your `#Container` wrapping div has a set width of 1000px, no matter what the viewport is. Plus I don't see any media queries being used?

Try adding media queries so it reduces in width as the viewport scales down:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    #Container {
        width: 720px;
    }
}
```

Add another for smaller viewports, perhaps so the `#Container` spans the entire width of a viewport that's <= 767px:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #Container {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

You can add and tailor as many as you like... Here's a useful guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries